# Number of smallest length of string, in C

Tags: c

I want to make a program, which prints the number of smallest length of string. I have a file of words, which I open from stdin and save it to buffer.

My code so far prints the length of each word. But I can't figure out how to compare these numbers.

For example in file are:

```
Hello
Hi
```

My program does:

```
6
3
```

The output should be:

```
3
```

I can't figure ou how to continue. Do you have any advice?

```
#include <stdio.h>

 int min_stat(char str[])
 {
    int min=0;
    for(int i=0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        min++;   
    }
    return min;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc < 1){
        fprintf(stderr,"Error\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char param = argv[1][0];
    int val=100;
    char buffer[val];
    if(param == '1')
    {
        while(fgets(buffer, val, stdin) != NULL)
        {
            int a = min_stat(buffer);
            printf("%d\n", a);
        }  
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OT: consider what happens if `argc <= 1` is true.

Comment: Yes, that's my mistake, it suppose to be `argc < 1` .Thanks for warning

Comment: No, `argc <= 1` is correct. What happens _after_ you printf `"Error"`?

Comment: My idea with that was, to make sure there is some parameter. If there wouldn't be, it should end .

Comment: Your idea is perfectly correct. The problem is, if there is no parameter (`argc <= 1`) you print `"Error`", but then the program doesn't stop but it continues.

Comment: Now, it should be okay?

Comment: Now for your actual problem: Take 4 small pieces of paper and write a different number on each of them, say 1, 2, 3 and 4 and put them into a box, shake the box. Now you take one piece of paper out of the box at a time, you look at the number and then you throw away the piece of paper. How can you determine which is the largest of the numbers?

Comment: Yes, now the errror handling is correct. See my previous comment for for your actual problem.

Comment: By remembering the first number and comparing it to second one. Then remember the larger number and comparing to third one. Until I have only one left

Comment: Obviously you've found the correct algorithm. Apply that to your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the minimum lenght of the string somewhere and update it if a shorter string is detected. Your `min_stat` function returns the number of characters of the string.

I would use something like this:

```
#define MAX_LENGHT 1000

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc < 1){
        fprintf(stderr,"Error\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char param = argv[1][0];
    int val=100;
    char buffer[val];

    /* the maximum possible lenght */
    int min_lenght = MAX_LENGHT;

    if(param == '1')
    {
        while(fgets(buffer, val, stdin) != NULL)
        {
            int a = min_stat(buffer);
             
            /* update the mimimum lenght if it is smaller 
               than the current value */
            if (a < min_lenght) {
                min_lenght = a;
            }

            printf("%d\n", a);
        }  
    }

    /* print the minimum lenght */
    printf("Minimum: %d\n", min_lenght);

    return 0;
}
```

You should not use a variable to initialize the char array, because you are using Variable Lenght Arrays (VLA) and not static arrays. If you are learning c you should use static arrays and so:

```
char buffer[MAX_LENGHT];
```

where `MAX_LENGHT` is a constant or a pre-processor definition.